# При нажатии на внутренний элемент активируются все чекбоксы а не один

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть такой скрипт

```
$('.plusproduct').click(function (){
        $('input').prop("checked", true);   
    });
```

И есть такие блоки из чекбоксов

```
<input type="checkbox" id="holodilnik" class="trigger">
                <label class="product" data-id="id2" for="holodilnik">
                    <div class="name" data-id="id2">Почистить холодильник</div>
                    <div class="product-container">
                        <button class="plusproduct" data-id="id2">+</button>
                        <div class="productsum" id="id2">0</div>
                        <button class="minusproduct" data-id="id2">-</button>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input type="checkbox" id="garderob" class="trigger">
                <label class="product" data-id="id3" for="garderob">
                    <div class="name" data-id="id3">Убраться в гардеробе</div>
                    <div class="product-container">
                        <button class="plusproduct" data-id="id3">+</button>
                        <div class="productsum" id="id3">0</div>
                        <button class="minusproduct" data-id="id3">-</button>
                    </div>
                </label>
```

Проблема в том что когда я нажимаю "+" тоесть .plusproduct у меня активируются оба чекбокса а мне нужно чтобы активировался только чекбокс внутри которого нажимался плюсик. Пробовал $('input', this) не помогло :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parents('label').prev('input').prop("checked", true)`:

```js
$('.plusproduct').click(function (){
  $(this).parents('label').prev('input').prop("checked", true);
    //saveint = parseInt(savediv.text());
    //saveint = saveint + 1;
    //savediv.text(saveint);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="elem" class="trigger">
<label class="product" for="elem">
  <div class="name">Помыть духовку</div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <button class="plusproduct" data-id="id1">+</button>
    <div class="productsum" id="id1">0 шт.</div>
    <button class="minusproduct" data-id="id1">-</button>
  </div>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="holodilnik" class="trigger">
<label class="product" data-id="id2" for="holodilnik">
  <div class="name" data-id="id2">Почистить холодильник</div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <button class="plusproduct" data-id="id2">+</button>
    <div class="productsum"  id="id2">0</div>
    <button class="minusproduct" data-id="id2">-</button>
  </div>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="garderob" class="trigger">
<label class="product" data-id="id3" for="garderob">
  <div class="name" data-id="id3">Убраться в гардеробе</div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <button class="plusproduct" data-id="id3">+</button>
    <div class="productsum"  id="id3">0</div>
    <button class="minusproduct" data-id="id3">-</button>
  </div>
</label>
```